# can anyone tell me whats wrong with this insert statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

the statement is,

```
INSERT INTO int_in_sales_cosmic_hdr
            ([sales_id],
             [description],
             [create_date],
             [update_date],
             [user_id],
             [start_date],
             [period_week],
             [action],
             [is_forecast])
SELECT DISTINCT Cast(Datepart(year, [create_date])AS NVARCHAR(10))
                + Cast(Datepart(week, [create_date])AS NVARCHAR(10)),
                [description],
                [create_date],
                Getdate(),
                CURRENT_USER(),
                [start_date],
                [period_week],
                [action],
                [is_forecast]
FROM   #temp_sales
```

the error is,

> Msg 120, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CDG_LoadData, Line 1641 The
>   select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the
>   insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of
>   INSERT columns.

the insert and select contains same number of columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove parenthesis from `CURRENT_USER`. `Current_User` is not a inbuilt function. It

> Returns the name of the current user

```
 INSERT INTO int_in_sales_cosmic_hdr
            ([sales_id],
             [description],
             [create_date],
             [update_date],
             [user_id],
             [start_date],
             [period_week],
             [action],
             [is_forecast])
SELECT DISTINCT Cast(Datepart(year, [create_date])AS NVARCHAR(10))
                + Cast(Datepart(week, [create_date])AS NVARCHAR(10)),
                [description],
                [create_date],
                Getdate(),
                CURRENT_USER,
                [start_date],
                [period_week],
                [action],
                [is_forecast]
FROM   #temp_sales
```

Comment: Any ideas as to why the error message complained about the number of columns not matching rather than the syntax being incorrect?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist- Parenthesis making the compiler not to consider `current_user` value so it is throwing number of values in select list is less than insert column list